# StakerStatus is not updating on my custom explorer

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, frontend

I have made a custom explorer of a substrate based blockchain, and when  i am chilling the staker, its status is not updating to inactive on the custom explorer, is there any RPC call or any other way for the same as it is perfectly updating on the polkadot{.js} explorer. We have the RPC for active status `api.derive.staking.electedInfo` and for waiting also `api.derive.staking.waitingInfo` is there anything similar to this for the chill/inactive mode.

Comment: Sounds cool! Wanna share your work with us? Also please point out the right page that seems to be working on the Apps UI - I think https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/search?q=chill will likely point you to the source to start looking for how it's done there.

Comment: Above function that you talking is to chill validator.I want to show the list of inactive validators .Is there any rpc ??